# Wrong output in finding the maximum sum of adjacent digits in a pyramid/triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I solving [Problem 18 on Project Euler](https://radiusofcircle.blogspot.com/2016/04/problem-18-project-euler-solution-with-python.html) and have written the code for it as below:

```
v = '''75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23'''.strip().split('\n')


last_ind = 0
max_sum = 75
for row in v[1:]:
    row = row.split(' ')
    num1 = int(row[last_ind])
    num2 = int(row[last_ind+1])
    if num1 > num2:
        max_sum+=num1
    else:
        max_sum+=num2
        last_ind = last_ind+1
        
print(max_sum)
```

I got the ANSWER AS **1064** but it's written `1074` everywhere. Can someone please suggest me what I might be doing wrong. By calculating every row by hands, I get `1064`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that the optimal path will always move down via the child with the greatest value, but this is not true. A child with a lesser value may open up a possibility (at lower layers) to find a much greater value, which more than compensates for the temporary less optimal value.

So your algorithm, in its first iteration will go from 75 to the 95 on the second row. But this turns out to be the wrong choice. You'll have to come up with a better algorithm. You will find inspiration in other Q&A about this particular challenge, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678131/project-euler-18-in-python-beginner).

Here you see the optimal path:

| path |
| --- |
| **75** |
| 95 **64** |
| 17 47 **82** |
| 18 35 **87** 10 |
| 20 04 **82** 47 65 |
| 19 01 23 **75** 03 34 |
| 88 02 77 **73** 07 63 67 |
| 99 65 04 **28** 06 16 70 92 |
| 41 41 26 56 **83** 40 80 70 33 |
| 41 48 72 33 47 **32** 37 16 94 29 |
| 53 71 44 65 25 43 **91** 52 97 51 14 |
| 70 11 33 28 77 73 17 **78** 39 68 17 57 |
| 91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 **58** 50 27 29 48 |
| 63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 **73** 16 69 87 40 31 |
| 04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 **93** 38 53 60 04 23 |

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you were on the row just before the bottom row, call it row `l`. Now for each number `m` on row `l`, ask (1) which of the (one or) two choices would be optimal to choose next? (2) what would the sum now look like at `m` if we added that optimal choice?

Now ask the same questions for the row just above `l`.